# Monerod has stopped working

Tags: monerod

Monerod was working correctly, but suddenly stopped.  I tried downloading the latest version (monero-gui-0.11.0.0) in the hopes that that would solve the problem, but it doesn't.  When I try to start the program through the terminal rather than via the GUI, I am told the program doesn't exist even though the ls command shows it very clearly.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04, and was doing so when it worked correctly earlier.

The bitmonero.log says:

`2017-09-14 10:57:06.331     7f1519564780    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:148   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2017-09-14 10:57:06.331     7f1519564780    ERROR   msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081`

And the monero-wallet-gui. log says:

`2017-09-14 10:56:52.394     7fab3bc417c0    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:148   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2017-09-14 10:56:52.792     7fab3bc417c0    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:156   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2017-09-14 10:56:52.991     7fab3bc417c0    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:156   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2017-09-14 10:56:53.037     7fab1bfff700    ERROR   net.http    contrib/epee/include/storages/portable_storage.h:161    portable_storage: wrong binary format - signature mismatch
2017-09-14 10:56:53.037     7fab1bfff700    ERROR   wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:2128 !r. THROW EXCEPTION: error::invalid_password
2017-09-14 10:56:53.037     7fab1bfff700    WARN    net.http    src/wallet/wallet_errors.h:707  /home/vagrant/slave/monero-core-ubuntu-amd64/build/monero/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:2128:N5tools5error16invalid_passwordE: invalid password
2017-09-14 10:56:53.038     7fab1bfff700    ERROR   WalletAPI   src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:504   Error opening wallet: invalid password
2017-09-14 10:56:53.077     7fab1bfff700    ERROR   WalletAPI   src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:553   Status_Critical - not storing wallet
2017-09-14 10:57:04.550     7fab1b7fe700    WARN    net.dns src/common/dns_utils.cpp:487    WARNING: no two valid MoneroPulse DNS checkpoint records were received`

Answer (score 1):

> I am told the program doesn't exist even though the ls command shows it very clearly.

Need more info here.  Sounds like `monerod` is just not in your `$PATH` perhaps?  If so, you need to use the full path to the executable.

> monero-wallet-gui. log says...

I see `invalid password` in the log, have you checked for sure that the password is correct? (remove all special characters / symbols to test).  Are you even using a username / password?

Are you sure that `monerod` is configured to accept incoming RPC on IP `127.0.0.1` and port `18081`? (the default)

Comment: Thank you.  The invalid password was a mistype and was fixed on the next try.  The settings page of the GUI definatly says localhost and 1881 for the port.  As nearly as I can tell from the logs, I am attempting to access 127.0.0.1.  I have two Ubuntu 14.04 computers, and the same problem occurs on both.  But I am also running a machine on Archlinux/Mate and the GUI and block chain work great on it, so the problem seems to be related to Ubuntu.

Comment: @user592440 If the password is fixed, please replace log message above with the current one. If the same setup works on another Linux machine, then it might be a firewall (like `ufw`) blocking the port?  I recommended the simple password because I once configured a password using `#` char and didn't realize it was being interpreted as a comment in the config file  ;-)